# Command not found error in Bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
  tempfile1="tempInfo1"
  tempfile2="tempInfo2"

  (otherfunction) $1 > "$tempfile1"  
  (otherfunction) $2 > "$tempfile2"

  if $(cmp "$tempfile1" "$tempfile2")
  then 
    echo "Two files are same"

    rm $tempfile1
    rm $tempfile2
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Two files are different" >&2
    rm $tempfile1
    rm $tempfile2
    exit 1
  fi
```

and I got

```
line 7: tempInfo1: command not found
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong, this is my first shell script, and I'm really confused. Or is there any other method I can compare the content of two files?

Comment: Instead of `if $(cmp "$tempfile1" "$tempfile2")`  you can do  `if cmp -s "$tempfile1" "$tempfile2"` and I suggest you verify your script via  https://shellcheck.net

Comment: It works! Really appreciate.

Comment: @TabrisNexus : When you did the `$(cmp ...)`, the `if` interprets the stdout of the cmp command as a command to be executed. This is not what you want.